# Apache Freemarker - Get repeating nodes along with child nodes

Tags: xml, xpath, freemarker

I am using Apache Freemarker and I currently want to parse the below xml structure using xPath approach.

```
<book>
  <title>Test Book</title>
  <chapter>
    <title>Ch1</title>
    <para>p1.1</para>
    <para>p1.2</para>
    <para>p1.3</para>
  </chapter>
  <chapter>
    <title>Ch2</title>
    <para>p2.1</para>
    <para>p2.2</para>
  </chapter>
</book>
```

I want to display the child nodes of the `chapter` node dynamically in the HTML output.
My desired output would be something like below:

```
Ch1
p1.1
p1.2
p1.3

Ch2
p2.1
p2.2
```

Would be great if someone can help me with a code snippet of how to get this using xPath approach.

I did try with the below approach which is failing:

```
<#list xml["//chapter/child::text()"] as p >
<p>${p["title"]}</p>
</#list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may need nested lists:

```
<#list xml["//chapter"] as t>
${t.title}
  <#list t[".//para"] as p>
    ${p}
   </#list>
</#list>
```

Output is your expected output.

Comment: I have a use case wherein I am processing a namespace xml with Freemarker. Below is the structure that I am processing using xPath approach. 
```<ns3:Books>
   <ns3:BookName>Book ABC</ns3:BookName>
   <ns3:BookId>1857669</ns3:BookId>
   <ns3:BookAuthor>John Doe</ns3:BookAuthor>
</ns3:Books>```
I am able to get the list of child nodes using ```<#list xml['//Books/*'] as p>```. How can I access the individual child node names from the list?

Comment: @JestinoSam It may be doable, but you should post it as a different question, as per SO policy.

Comment: okay, sure. Just posted a question on the same - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63080567/apache-freemarker-get-node-name-from-an-xpath-list. It would be great if you can take a look & answer the same!