# Apache Freemarker - Get node name from an xPath list

Tags: xml, xpath, freemarker

I have a use case wherein I am processing a namespace xml with Freemarker. Below is the structure that I am processing using xPath approach.

```
<ns3:Books>
<ns3:BookName>Book ABC</ns3:BookName>
<ns3:BookId>1857669</ns3:BookId>
<ns3:BookAuthor>John Doe</ns3:BookAuthor>
</ns3:Books>
```

I am able to get the list of child nodes using
`<#list xml['//Books/*'] as p>`.
I tried the below way:

```
<#list xml['//Books/*'] as p>
${p["BookName"]}
</#list>
```

The above code snippet is not able to get the node name from the xPath list.
How can I access the individual child node names `BookName,BookId,BookAuthor` from the list?

Comment: Are you looking only for the book name, or also Id and author?

Comment: @JackFleeting I am looking for all the node values under the ```Books``` nodelist. I want to access the nodes by the names so that I can have control of displaying the nodes in the html output.

Comment: I'm curious: did the answer work?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you have an xml with namespaces, and you have to take that into account in creating your xpath expression.

So, first, your actual xml would probably look something like this:

```
xml = <ns3:Books xmlns:ns3="http://example.com/whatever">>    
<ns3:BookName>Book ABC</ns3:BookName>    
<ns3:BookId>1857669</ns3:BookId>    
<ns3:BookAuthor>John Doe</ns3:BookAuthor> 
</ns3:Books>
```

Your template also has to take namespaces into account. Once you do that, you can access the individual nodes in the xml by their tag name and extract the text. There may be a shorter way of doing what you want than the one below, but this will give you each element separately:

```
<#ftl ns_prefixes={"ns3":"http://example.com/whatever"}>

  <#list xml[".//ns3:Books//ns3:BookName/text()"] as name>
    ${name}
   </#list>

  <#list xml[".//ns3:Books//ns3:BookId/text()"] as id>
    ${id}
   </#list>

  <#list xml[".//ns3:Books//ns3:BookAuthor/text()"] as author>
    ${author}
   </#list>
```

Output:

```
  Book ABC

1857669

John Doe
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can remove the namespaces you can achive what you want in 2 ways:

1.You can go to the node Books and list only the children that you want

```
<#list body['//Books'] as p>
${p["BookName"]}
${p["BookId"]}
${p["BookAuthor"]}
</#list>
```

2.You can list directly all the children that the node Books has

```
<#list body['//Books/*'] as p>
${p}
</#list>
```